# Statemachine with multiple transtions with same trigger/event but different guard

Tags: uml, state-machine, statechart

If I have a state S1 with 2 transitions both with triggered by an event 'A', but one of them has as a guard `x !=0` and the other doesn't. What would be the expected behavior when guard is valid (`x ==1`)?

1. Unpredictable
2. Transition with guard is taken
3. Transition without guard is taken

I don't remember reading about not being able to have 2 transitions with the same event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `x != 0`, e.g. `x== 1`, then the transition with `x == 0` is not enabled, the other, unguarded one is. the other is fired.

if `x == 0`, then both of the transitions are enabled. this is a situation of the so-called "conflicting transitions" (see UML [Spec.  2.4.1](http://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/doc?formal/2011-08-06.pdf)., p. 575). Conflict resolution is generally rather complicated, see UML Spec. In your specific case, where both transitions leave the same state, the result is non-deterministic: either one  of the transitions may be taken

Comment: I just realized that my guard explanation was wrong, but the second part of your answer explains it. You deserve double check.